# How to find out the assemblies that TIBCO universal installer tries to download?

Tags: tibco

When running TIBCO universal installer, I get the following error:

```
(Oct 15, 2019 11:15:47 AM), Install, com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCORunInstaller, dbg.Debug, executing subsequence action: action-downloadMissingAssemblies
(Oct 15, 2019 11:15:47 AM), Install, com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCOInstaller, dbg.Debug, actionClass = com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCODownloadAssembliesPanelWizardAction
(Oct 15, 2019 11:15:47 AM), Install, com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCOInstaller, dbg.Debug, id = action-downloadMissingAssemblies
(Oct 15, 2019 11:15:47 AM), Install, com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCODownloadAssembliesPanelWizardAction, dbg.Debug, setting wizard action property: showProgress=false
(Oct 15, 2019 11:15:47 AM), Install, com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCOInstaller, dbg.Debug, showProgress = false
(Oct 15, 2019 11:15:47 AM), Install, com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCOInstaller, dbg.Debug, ERROR::WizardAction exception encountered.
(Oct 15, 2019 11:15:47 AM), Install, com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCOInstaller, dbg.Debug, null
(Oct 15, 2019 11:15:47 AM), Install, com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCOInstaller, dbg.Debug, 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCOUniversalInstallerAction.executeWizardAction(TIBCOUniversalInstallerAction.java:311)
    at com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCORunInstaller._executeWizardAction(TIBCORunInstaller.java:230)
    at com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCORunInstaller._executeSubSequence(TIBCORunInstaller.java:311)
    at com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCORunInstaller._runSequence(TIBCORunInstaller.java:118)
    at com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCORunInstaller._runInstallSequences(TIBCORunInstaller.java:78)
    at com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCORunInstaller.run(TIBCORunInstaller.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCOUniversalInstallerAction.executeWizardAction(TIBCOUniversalInstallerAction.java:384)
    at com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCORunWizardAction.execute(TIBCORunWizardAction.java:26)
    at com.installshield.wizard.StandardWizardListener.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.installshield.wizard.StandardWizardListener.currentBeanChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.installshield.wizard.Wizard$RunThread.run(Wizard.java:1829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCODownloadInterface.calculateTotalSize(TIBCODownloadInterface.java:854)
    at com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCODownloadInterface.displayDownloadMultiTasks(TIBCODownloadInterface.java:396)
    at com.tibco.installer.util.TIBCODownloadInterface.displayDownloadMultiTasks(TIBCODownloadInterface.java:382)
    at com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCODownloadAssembliesPanelWizardAction._downloadAssemblies(TIBCODownloadAssembliesPanelWizardAction.java:93)
    at com.tibco.installer.wizard.action.TIBCODownloadAssembliesPanelWizardAction.run(TIBCODownloadAssembliesPanelWizardAction.java:37)
    ... 19 more
```

Because of the message `action-downloadMissingAssemblies` I believe that it tries to download some missing assembly.

How can I find out what exactly it tries to download? Is there a way to disable such download and prevent the NPE from occuring?

**Update 1:** Here is the command I use to start the installation: `./TIBCOUniversalInstaller-lnx-x86.bin -silent -V responseFile="TIBCOUniversalInstaller_TRA_5.7.3.silent"`

Comment: which product are you trying to install? as far as I know, all TIBCO installers are standalone and don't need any install-time-download.

Comment: @Sudhendu This error occurs when installing remote agent, Hawk, Rendezvous.

Comment: hmm. that's strange. can you provide the product version? And what do you mean by remote agent? Remote agent of what product?

Comment: @Sudhendu Sorry, it's runtime agent, not remote agent. I tried installing versions 5.7.1 and 5.7.3.

Comment: Stranger again. To best of my knowledge, TIBCO setups are single standlalone installer with all the binding in the installer. It should not download anything. Where did you get the setup from? Null pointer exception can also occur if there is access issue on the installation path. Did you try running with admin previliges?

Comment: @Sudhendu I am running the installer as `root`.

Comment: @Sudhendu The distribution archives were on the server of the company that I work for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200932/discussion-between-sudhendu-and-dp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TIBCO universal installer with `-console` instead of `-silent` fixed the problem.